# AWS Cloudformation with Custom Resource stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Good evening, I am writing because I have a problem with CloudFormation. I am trying to deploy with Cloud Formation a Lambda function that is invoke automatically from the Stack.

Here it the lambda with response.SUCCESS utilization

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
      const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
      const response = require('cfn-response');
      exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
          const results = [];
          try {
              const data = await ec2.describeRegions().promise();
              const allRegions = data.Regions.map(region => region.RegionName);
              for (const reg of allRegions) {
                  try {
                      const ec2C = new AWS.EC2({ region });
                      const vpcs = await ec2Client.describeVpcs().promise();
                      const defaultVpc = vpcs.Vpcs.find(vpc => vpc.IsDefault);

                      if (defaultVpc) {
                          results.push('Default VPC in ' + region + ':' + defaultVpc.VpcId);
                      } else {
                          results.push('No default VPC found in ' + region);
                      }
                  } catch (error) {
                      results.push('Error in ' + region + ':' + error.message);
                  }
              }
          } catch (error) {
              results.push('Error fetching active regions: ' + error.message);
              response.send(event, context, response.FAILED);
          }

     
          
          response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, JSON.stringify(results));
      };
```

And then the CustomResource that will invoke my lambda

```
 InvokeLambdaAfterDeploy:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
   Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
```

The resources are created correctly, the lambda is also invoked, and in CloudWatch I can see the "Status" status: "SUCCESS".
The problem occurs when analyzing the Stack, the creation of the CustomResource remains stuck on CREATING_IN_PROGRESS
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing sync and async patterns in your lambda handler.

A lambda handler can signal the end of its execution either by [fulfilling a promise it returns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) or by [exhausting the event loop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-callback) in the NodeJS instance that runs the lambda (the old way).

Since your handler is marked as async, it does return a promise which is fulfilled immediately upon return.

`response.send` is not an async function, it doesn't return a promise, so you can't await on it in a meaningful way. There is a race condition between the series of callbacks inside `response.send` and the promise, which the promise always wins.

It means that `cfn-response` doesn't have a chance to send anything into the response, because the response stream is closed the moment the promise fulfils, so CloudFormation doesn't get a report from your custom handler (neither success nor failure).

You can still see stuff in CloudWatch logs, because closing the response doesn't immediately stop NodeJS execution. The Lambda runtime can freeze it though, but it takes a little bit of time to do that.

It doesn't look like there's an async/await version of `cfn-response`, but this module is but a [couple dozen lines of code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule-source) and it's easy to roll your own.

Comment: Here is the module that you send applied in my lambda. But still locked in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. What im doing wrong?

https://pastebin.com/7V89ZFWY

Comment: @BearGrillz: you're awaiting on the function `send` which is not async and does not return a promise. This await is not doing anything useful.

Comment: ok thats correct, but without await still doesn't work. Something else missing?

Comment: @BearGrillz: how familiar are you with JS? I'm not really sure how to improve this answer without turning it into a book on fundamentals on the async pattern in JS.

Comment: very very low unfortunately

Comment: @BearGrillz: if you post this code and ask how to convert it to async, it would make a good new question. Just please make sure to read up on it a little bit and make an effort to understand what's going on prior to asking.